# awk array initialization at each line fails

Tags: awk

I have a log file where each line contains some numbers separated by `,`. I just wanted to some operation with each number. It seemed easy with awk, but somehow i got stuck. The array which i'm using to split each line, is getting initialized only once at the first line. After that the array is not getting clear. split is supposed to clear the array first then use it, i have even used `delete array`. But still the problem persists. Any help will be appreciated.
Below is some example;
This is a sample file

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ cat log
1,2,3
2
9
1,4
5,7
7
8
6,2
```

This is what i'm getting

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ awk '{print "New Line " $1; delete a; split($1,a,","); for(var in a){ print "Array Element " var; } }' log
New Line 1,2,3
Array Element 1
Array Element 2
Array Element 3
New Line 2
Array Element 1
New Line 9
Array Element 1
New Line 1,4
Array Element 1
Array Element 2
New Line 5,7
Array Element 1
Array Element 2
New Line 7
Array Element 1
New Line 8
Array Element 1
New Line 6,2
Array Element 1
Array Element 2
```

But below is what I am expecting

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ awk '{print "New Line " $1; delete a; split($1,a,","); for(var in a){ print "Array Element " var; } }' log
New Line 1,2,3
Array Element 1
Array Element 2
Array Element 3
New Line 2
Array Element 2
New Line 9
Array Element 9
New Line 1,4
Array Element 1
Array Element 4
New Line 5,7
Array Element 5
Array Element 7
New Line 7
Array Element 7
New Line 8
Array Element 8
New Line 6,2
Array Element 6
Array Element 2
```

Mine is GNU Awk 3.1.5. Also I have found another way by using combination of shell and awk, ( running awk individually on each line) but i want to know what I am  doing wrong

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: when i'm getting `New Line 5,7`, then the next 2 lines should print 5 and 7, but instead it is printing 1,2 which was fed to the array at the beginning.

Comment: Well I mean a complete output. It will be easier to work with it to check what it is not correct

Comment: I have updated the question. As you can see, Array Elements are not getting updated after split call. I am going to add further processing for each array element. So just printing is not what i'm asking, I'm looking for what mistake i have done in splitting each line into an array. Or why the array is not getting updated after each split call.

Comment: parkydr found the problem, I was checking the index value, instead of using the index. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (var in array)` sets var to the index of the next element of the array so `var` is the index, not the contents. Use

```
print "Array Element " a[var]
```

Comment: Ahhh,, silly me :P, I have been looking into it for so long and did not see this. Thanks a lot @parkydr.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `split()` just set the field separator:

```
awk -F, '{print "New Line",$0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "Array Element",$i}' log
New Line 1,2,3
Array Element 1
Array Element 2
Array Element 3
New Line 2
Array Element 2
New Line 9
Array Element 9
New Line 1,4
Array Element 1
Array Element 4
New Line 5,7
Array Element 5
Array Element 7
New Line 7
Array Element 7
New Line 8
Array Element 8
New Line 6,2
Array Element 6
Array Element 2
```

Comment: Actually I have further processing to do where for each element, i'll be iterating over the array many times, So for me, it was important to keep them in array.

Comment: All you are doing with `split()` is what `awk` already does with fields, you are deleting the array after every record anyway. What ever further processing your are doing with your array `a[var]` can be done with `$i`. You are almost certainly handling the field separation unnecessarily.

Comment: Here in log, i'm getting the id of requests. 1 session in 1 line, ids following order of request. I had to check for each session, if one id is requesting for multiple times and how many times. So I was actually putting them to another array. At the end, i was checking for any rouge id which makes repeated request in each session and all in a dir without write permission(for safety). Actually i need to check if in a line, one id is present multiple times, and if yes,how many times. that time awk array seemed a good approach. Now I'm curious if there is a better solution. Any suggestions...

Comment: @abasu for the case you described I would use an array where the keys are the ID's and the values are the counts however I wouldn't manually split the fields I'd set `FS` appropriately.

Comment: Initially i started with `FS = ","` then storing them as `array[id]++`. But immediately one problem came up, some ids will request almost in each session(that is valid). But as the number of sessions grew, count for those ids increased. Ultimately I had a list where rouge ids were present, but valid ids were also present. To solve that i had to take this approach. I had to set up a cut off also for minimum number of requests in a session to qualify as a rouge id.